# How to hide venv in PyCharm Project View

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-venv

I just updated to Python 3.7.2 in PyCharm 2018.3.2 and a new `venv` folder showed up in my project view. I've read several threads on stackoverflow but haven't found a solution to remove the `venv` from Project View which is what I want.

I read it's "best practices" to keep the `venv` with the project but currently I'd rather have it separated and removed from Project View.

Does anyone know how to do this?

**EDIT:** The problem was I had configured a `venv` in the PyCharm "Project Interpreter page". If you want to keep everything minimal there's no need for a `venv` or anaconda, although the PyCharm "Project Interpreter page" layout suggests so. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can exclude and hide the 'venv' directory (along with other excluded directories) as follows:

1. Mark it as excluded: right click on the 'venv' directory -> Mark Directory as -> Excluded.
2. Hide excluded files: click on the tiny gear icon in the Project View panel and *de*select 'Show Excluded Files' from the drop down menu.

Comment: I didn't know about this 1,2, @John. It actually didn't solve the problem since `venv` can't be excluded or hidden that way but instead should be disabled in PyCharm "Project Interpreter page". But I appreciate the hint you gave and it helped me towards finding a solution.

Comment: Your question was how to 'hide' venv and have it 'removed from Project View', not how to 'disable' venv altogether :-).

Comment: Yes I know. But hiding it actually didn't work (works for other folders but not for venv). That's why it had to be removed. And yes, you did address the question exactly as it was placed :)

Comment: Which version you are using? I've tested my answer on PyCharm 2018.3.1 and it worked as expected.

Comment: I'm using PyCharm 2018.3.2...To reproduce what happened to me: "Setting New Project"->"Project Interpreters"->"Show All"->"Add New"->"Virtual Env"...If you add it there you can't make it invisible in "Project View" latter using the method you indicated. At least I couldn't. I had to backtrack the indicated path and turn of `venv` there.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the 'New UI' then you can exclude the directory as follows:

1. Right click on the directory and hover 'Mark Directory As' and then select  'Excluded'. This should highlight the file orange to signify this.
2. On the project view panel click on the 3 vertical dots in the top right, then select 'Tree Appearance' and deselect 'Show Excluded Files'

This is a very similar answer to MEE's, but for the new UI. I couldn't comment as this was my first-time using stack overflow so I thought I'd post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

I often use a lot of methods. The general folder can be hidden, only the venv folder is not allowed, so I can only delete venv, re-configure venv, when re-configuration, do not put venv in the project file In the folder, put a new Venv folder for all applications.

```
E.g
--Diango
----Myproject
----venv
------Myprojectvenv
```

Comment: I was intending to self-answer this in the near future. I agree with your answer, but it can still be expanded.